# Removing duplicate rows from hashtable

Tags: c#, datatable, key, duplicates, hashtable

Hi there I have a grid which is being populated with user results on educational courses they have taken part in. For each user they have their own grid showing them each course they have done and their status of each time they have tried the course. For example:

CourseTitle   | Status
Excel,                                     incomplete
Body Language,                             complete
Body Language,                             abandoned
Body Language,                             incomplete
Body Language,                             completed
Body Language,                             completed

After removing duplicates the table should look like this:

CourseTitle   | Status
Excel,                                     incomplete
Body Language,                             complete
Body Language,                             abandoned
Body Language,                             incomplete

I was trying to do it like this:

public static DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName, string colTitle)
    {
        Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
        ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

```
    foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
    {

        if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]) && hTable.Contains(drow[colTitle]))
        {
            duplicateList.Add(drow);
        }
        else
            hTable.Add(drow[colName], drow[colTitle]);
    }

    foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
        dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

    return dTable;
}
```

But this way gives me an error:
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'incomplete' c#

I now know that you cannot have duplicated keys in key,value pairs. Does anyone know a way around this or a different method I could use to solve this problem. Sorry forgot to add that this needs to be added to a datatable.

Cheers, James

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dictionnary or Dictionnary instead of a Hashtable.

If you want to keep all statuses use Dictionary>. The key is the course and you will have the list of statuses in the value part (list).

If i take your code it will be like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {

            if (values.ContainsKey(drow[colName]))
            {
                if(values[row[colName]] == null)
                    values[row[colName]] = new List<string>();

                if (!values[row[colName]].Contains(drow[colTitle]))
                    values[row[colName]].Add(drow[colTitle]);
            }
        }

        return values;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my dictionary definitions did not pass sorry

Comment: if (values.Contains(drow[colName])&& values.Contains(drow[colTitle])) this line gives an error. Does not contain definition contains

Comment: Sorry man I already tried ContainsKey before you made this edit. It doesnt work

Comment: The results for the grid come from a stored procedure which is added to a datatable I've called dt. So I will have to do dt = methodwhichremovesduplicates(dt, colName, colTitle) it says it cannot convert Dictionary<string, List<string>> to datatable. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This problem is still unsolved :( the method is fine but when I try this dt = RemoveDuplicateRows(dt, "status","course_title"); it throws an error obviously because the dictionary needs to be converted into a datatable somehow. I'm pretty new this stuff so sorry if this question sounds kinda dumb